# Need to remove whitespace from between two symbols

Tags: javascript, regex

Need to remove whitespace from between two colons. So the output of `: test :` would be `:test:`. I got it to detect everything between :: but now I need it to match only the whitespace. This is the regex that matches everything: `(?<=\:)(.*?)(?=\:)`

Comment: Do you only need to remove the whitespace around the word, or can there be whitespace in the middle that also needs to be removed? Does `: word1 word2 :` become `:word1word2:`?

Comment: @Barmar it really doesn't matter in my context because the there will only be single words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
": test :".replace(/: *(.*?) *:/g,":$1:")
```

```js
let a = ": test :".replace(/: *(.*?) *:/g,":$1:")

console.log(a);
```

If you wanna only remove spaces from string then use simply

```
": test :".replace(/ /g,'')
```

```js
let a = ": test :".replace(/ /g,'')

console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try capturing colon and `replace()`:

```
/\s*(:)\s*/gi
```

### Demo

```js
var str = `fbflb : vfkvbfkvb : otjtjb : hih igvjyfv ugukgu ugug `

var rgx = /\s*(:)\s*/gi;

var res = str.replace(rgx, '$1');

console.log(res);
```

Comment: You can improve your regexp in this way: `": test :".replace(/ *: */g,':')`

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski your improvement is more streamlined, but I wanted to show the OP the use of capture groups.

Answer (score 0):

Use Replace and capturing group

```js
let str = ': test :'

let op = str.replace(/(:)\s+(.*?)\s+(:)/g, "$1$2$3")
let op1 = str.replace(/:(.*?):/g,':$1:' )

console.log(op);
console.log(op1)
```

Comment: yours is removing the colons also

Answer (score 0):

The following regex will remove all space characters from a string. \s represents any "space" type of character including tabs. the 'g' flag will perform multiple matches.

```
let text = ': test :'
let textWithoutSpaces = text.replace(/\s/g, '');
// textWithoutSpaces === ':test:'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```js
var s = " test : test : test";
console.log(
  s.replace(/:[^:]+:/g, function (m) { return m.replace(/\s+/g, ''); })
)
```

**Details**

- `/:[^:]+:/g` - matches all substrings that start with `:`, then have 1+ chars other than `:` and then `:`
- `m` is the matched text found, it is passed to the callback method in `replace` method
- `m.replace(/\s+/g, '')` removes all 1+ consecutive whitespace chars inside that match, and after this, the text is returned, and pasted back into the result.